# How to add custom html platform views in new flutter web

Tags: html, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to add custom video with html platform view to my flutter web project (1.9 tech preview) and i can't seem to find anything close to the old functions that allowed me to do this on the old flutter_web

I want something equivalent to this any help is welcome.

```
ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'hello-world-html',
      (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
        ..width = '640'
        ..height = '360'
        ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IyFZznAk69U'
        ..style.border = 'none');
```

Comment: hi, This code should work as it is. The IDE's might show the import of `dart:html` as an error but when you run the app the compiler will work just fine and the IFrame will be rendered. Did you try running the app. Also make sure you followed the steps mentioned in [this wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-from-package:flutter_web-to-the-Flutter-SDK). Make sure this step is done `flutter config --enable-web` before running the app. When you do this Chrome is added as one of your target device and hence `flutter run -d chrome` will work fine.

Comment: Well i tried running it, the problem is not the flutter html library error but the use of flutter_web_ui stuff, cause from the docs i understand everything has moved to normal material flutter so i should not use the old libraries. All i found maybe promising is the platformViewRegistry in flutter_services but it does not have a registerViewFactory function. I will try adding the old libraries and maybe using both of them and see if that works but i am not sure it will

Comment: Ok so it actually runs but has like 5 errors constantly all i needed to do was use dart:ui thanks for the help

Comment: Yes. I was just putting up an example to show it works just fine.. :) Glad it worked..

Comment: @user9158852: I can't find any working example. Maybe you have a link somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `'dart:ui'` with `import 'dart:ui' as ui`. Otherwise you'll get a warning from `ui.platformViewRegistry`.